# What's the correct ARMv7 to ARMv8 NEON port of this matrix multiplication code?

Tags: assembly, simd, neon, armv8

```
    // http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0425/DAI0425_migrating_an_application_from_ARMv5_to_ARMv7_AR.pdf
// p. 4-21

.macro mul_col_f32 res_q, col0_d, col1_d
vmul.f32 \res_q, q8, \col0_d[0] @ multiply col element 0 by matrix col 0
vmla.f32 \res_q, q9, \col0_d[1] @ multiply-acc col element 1 by matrix col 1
vmla.f32 \res_q, q10, \col1_d[0] @ multiply-acc col element 2 by matrix col 2
vmla.f32 \res_q, q11, \col1_d[1] @ multiply-acc col element 3 by matrix col 3
.endm

// http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100748_0606_00_en/lmi1470147220260.html
// http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203j/Cacjfjei.html

.globl  mat44mulneon
.p2align 2 // what's this ?
.type mat44mulneon,%function
mat44mulneon:
.fnstart // not recognized by eclipse syntax coloring?
// ---------
vld1.32 {d16-d19}, [r1]! @ load first eight elements of matrix 0
vld1.32 {d20-d23}, [r1]! @ load second eight elements of matrix 0
vld1.32 {d0-d3}, [r2]! @ load first eight elements of matrix 1.
vld1.32 {d4-d7}, [r2]! @ load second eight elements of matrix 1.
mul_col_f32 q12, d0, d1 @ matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 0
mul_col_f32 q13, d2, d3 @ matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 1
mul_col_f32 q14, d4, d5 @ matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 2
mul_col_f32 q15, d6, d7 @ matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 3
vst1.32 {d24-d27}, [r0]! @ store first eight elements of result.
vst1.32 {d28-d31}, [r0]! @ store second eight elements of result.
// ---------
bx lr // Return by branching to the address in the link register.
.fnend
```

The code above, which I found on an ARM site (see links in comments), works on my ARM Cortex A9 machine, i.e. a ARMv7 one.

I am now trying to get this to run on a ARMv8 / aarch64 CPU.
I have found this slide:
[porting to ARM64](http://my.presentations.techweb.com/events/esc/boston/2017/conference/download/5299)

At the very end, it shows a matrix multiplication code. But it uses loops and I guess (correct me if I'm not seeing this right) the code I posted would be faster if ported to the new ARMv8 mnemonics.
The linked document also shows some v7 -> v8 changes, so e.g. I changed things like vmul.32 to fmul and so forth. The register names given in the example do not match the one in the code posted above. Since I am not exactly fluent in any ARM asm, I don't know what the equivalents are here.
E.g. when I build my project, I get an error like:

```
operand 1 must be a SIMD vector register list -- `st1 {d24-d27},[r0]
```

I'm not sure that would be the only problem, though, so I rather ask:
What changes need to be done to the code to run on the aarch64 machine?

Comment: Don’t know answer to your question, but why are you using assembly? Here’s C++ code that probably implements what you want: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/master/Inc/DirectXMathMatrix.inl#L261-L293

Comment: @ Soonts thanks, I will try that. I read somewhere that SIMD intrinsics can't do some things that assembler can do (was it multi word loading...) and therefore using (the proper) assembler code would be still faster. But maybe that's changed or was/is only true for other SIMD than NEON - alas I don't remember the details.

Comment: Indeed, there’re couple edge cases. But in my experience, it’s very hard to beat well-written intrinsics code. Compilers seem to know instruction latencies and reorder them accordingly. C++ is easier to write because automatic register allocation, type safety, constant propagation in optimizer. And they portable within architectures, i.e. from x86 to AMD64, and from ARMv7 to v8.

Comment: @Soonts: Last I heard (~6 months ago), gcc/clang for ARM were still very bad at optimizing intrinsics (and the surrounding scalar code).  e.g. extra store/reload, redundant register-copying, etc is the kind of thing I remember from looking at the asm output.  It's strange, because they're fine with x86 SSE/AVX, and PowerPC Altivec.  But unless that's changed, there's still a use-case for hand-written asm on ARM specifically.

Comment: @Soonts My assembly version of Low Density Parity Check is more than 3 times as fast as the intrinsics version written by none other than myself. I wouldn't call that couple edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough AArch64 version of that routine:

```
.macro mul_col_f32 res, col
    fmul \res, v16.4s, \col[0] // multiply col element 0 by matrix col 0
    fmla \res, v17.4s, \col[1] // multiply-acc col element 1 by matrix col 1
    fmla \res, v18.4s, \col[2] // multiply-acc col element 2 by matrix col 2
    fmla \res, v19.4s, \col[3] // multiply-acc col element 3 by matrix col 3
.endm

.globl  mat44mulneon
mat44mulneon:
    ld1 {v16.4s, v17.4s, v18.4s, v19.4s}, [x1] 
    ld1 {v0.4s,  v1.4s,  v2.4s,  v3.4s},  [x2] 
    mul_col_f32 v24.4s, v0.s // matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 0
    mul_col_f32 v25.4s, v1.s // matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 1
    mul_col_f32 v26.4s, v2.s // matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 2
    mul_col_f32 v27.4s, v3.s // matrix 0 * matrix 1 col 3
    st1 {v24.4s, v25.4s, v26.4s, v27.4s}, [x0] 
ret
```

A few non-comprehensive notes about the conversion, in addition to general things mentioned in the linked presentation:

- You can load up to 64 bytes with one `ld1` instruction, compared to 32 bytes with `vld1` in AArch32. This avoids the need for incrementing the r0/r1/r2 or x0/x1/x2 pointers
- I left out the OS/binary format specific `.fnstart`, `.fnend` and `.type`, they can be readded in the same places as in the original version if wanted
- For AArch64 assembly, `@` isn't a comment character any longer
- The `col` parameter to `mul_col_f32` is in the form `v0.s`, contrary to `v0.4s`. When selecting a specific lane, after concatenating with the `[0]` suffix in the macro, one should omit the number of lanes, e.g. to pick the first lane of the `v0.4s` register, it should be written as `v0.s[0]`. The GNU assembler does allow `v0.4s[0]`, but other assemblers (both the Clang/LLVM built-in assembler, and Microsoft's armasm64) only allow the former syntax.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, this version is 5% faster than the one in the linked porting presentation, on a Cortex A72.